# C# DateTime Format and Comparison

Tags: c#, datetime, boolean, comparison, overlap

I'm writing a course scheduler for my university, and I'm having some trouble with comparisons in C#. For each course, the given datetime is in a string format like so:

```
 string Start_Time = "10:00";
 string End_Time = "10:50";
```

I need to convert these to a DateTime format (preferably restricted to HH:mm), and then do comparisons to make sure that there is no overlap between courses. My current code to check looks like this.

```
static bool checkTimes(Courses courseOne, Courses courseTwo)
    {
        bool overlapChecker = false;

        // Get comparison values for course times
        DateTime s1 = Convert.ToDateTime(courseOne.Start_Time);
        DateTime s2 = Convert.ToDateTime(courseTwo.Start_Time);
        DateTime e1 = Convert.ToDateTime(courseOne.End_Time);
        DateTime e2 = Convert.ToDateTime(courseTwo.End_Time);

        // Check for overlapping days of the week
        foreach (char c1_days in courseOne.Days)
        {
            foreach (char c2_days in courseTwo.Days)
            {
                if (c1_days == c2_days)
                {
                    overlapChecker = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // If there are any overlapping days, compare DateTimes of courses for overlap
        if (overlapChecker == true)
        {
            // Compare all possibilities of time overlap
            if ((s2 >= s1 && s2 <= e1) || (e1 >= s1 && e1 <= e2))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Currently, this is not working. I'm not quite sure where I went wrong, but any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `s1`? `s2`? `e1`? `e2`? `overlapChecker `? _Don't guess, run it and see._

Comment: can you please add Course class definition and how you call checkTimes ?

Comment: If possible, also add `Courses` class with some instances to play around with. Will certainly help others figure out the code precisely and easily.

Comment: you can replace `overlapChecker` foreach loops with this: `var overlapChecker = courseOne.Days.Any(d => courseTwo.Days.Contains(d))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a rextester with few assumption here - http://rextester.com/UDI9335

**Assumptions:**

1. your `Course` class is as follows.

   ```
   public class Course {
       public string cName { get; set; }
       public string Start_Time { get; set; }
       public string End_Time { get; set; }
       public List<string> Days { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. classes occur at the same time for all given days. (per your code)
3. `Days` is the `List` of `strings`, I momentarily thought of list or array of characters like `M, T, W, T, F` but this would have given incorrect results since `T` is being repeated. for Tuesday and Thursday

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Course c1 = new Course{
                cName = "Course 1",
                Start_Time = "10:00",
                End_Time = "10:50",
                Days = new List<string>{ "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"}
            };

            Course c2 = new Course{
                cName = "Course 2",
                Start_Time = "10:40",
                End_Time = "11:20",
                Days = new List<string>{ "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"}
            };

            Course c3 = new Course{
                cName = "Course 3",
                Start_Time = "11:30",
                End_Time = "12:20",
                Days = new List<string>{ "Mon", "Tue", "Fri"}
            };


            bool areC1C2Clashing = areCoursesClashing(c1, c2);
            Console.WriteLine("Are c1 & c2 clashing - " + areC1C2Clashing);
            Console.WriteLine();

            bool areC2C3Clashing = areCoursesClashing(c2, c3);
            Console.WriteLine("Are c2 & c3 clashing - " + areC2C3Clashing);
            Console.WriteLine();

            bool areC1C3Clashing = areCoursesClashing(c1, c3);
            Console.WriteLine("Are c1 & c3 clashing - " + areC1C3Clashing);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public static bool areCoursesClashing(Course cA, Course cB){
            bool clashDetected = false;
            foreach(var coruseDay in cA.Days){
                if(cB.Days.Contains(coruseDay)){

                    DateTime cAStartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(cA.Start_Time, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    DateTime cAEndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(cA.End_Time, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    DateTime cBStartTime = DateTime.ParseExact(cB.Start_Time, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    DateTime cBEndTime = DateTime.ParseExact(cB.End_Time, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                    if( cAStartTime < cBEndTime && cBStartTime < cAEndTime){
                        Console.WriteLine("WARNING!!! Classes clash for --> " + cA.cName + " & " + cB.cName);
                        clashDetected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return clashDetected;
        }
    }

    public class Course {
        public string cName { get; set; }
        public string Start_Time { get; set; }
        public string End_Time { get; set; }
        public List<string> Days { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> WARNING!!! Classes clash for --> Course 1 & Course 2
>
> Are c1 & c2 clashing - True
>
> Are c2 & c3 clashing - False
>
> Are c1 & c3 clashing - False

Comment: Thank you! I had to alter the code in here a bit, but this did solve my problem. 


As a side note, I used string value with the characters "MTWRF" for days of the week, that way I could store Course.Days as a string reduce the space needed to store a list. To check for comparisons I just ran through the string characters with a nested foreach loop. The complexity might technically be O(N^2), but since the max value of N is 5 (and really it's 4 for the programming I'm writing), I felt that was pretty acceptable.

Comment: Ah, I see what you did with `Days`. I couldn’t think of that because of repeating T as I said, but glad my input helped.

Answer (score -2):

You can 2 steps.
First => in the model "Courses" create methods for convert the string to datetime, like:

```
public DateTime StartTime()
{
    return new DateTime(2018,6,18,this.Start_Time.split(':')[0],this.Start_Time.split[1]);
}
```

Second => Override the method equals of Courses:

```
public override bool equals(object entity)
{
    var temp = entity as Courses;
    if (temp == null) return false;
    //Logics for a Course is equal to another Course
    If (this.StartTime == temp.StartTime)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

And you can't have a method "CheckTimes", simply call:

```
bool result = CourseOne.equals ( CouseTwo );
```